# Test if user clicked true or false

Tags: javascript, html

I'm able to evaluate the `value` of the `option` as true but not as false.
It never gets to "clicked no"

How come?

https://jsfiddle.net/9wvp0ktd/

```js
const versionNum = document.querySelector('#version-num');
const jarName = document.querySelector('#jar-name');
const getLatest = document.querySelector('#get-latest-yn');
getLatest.onclick = function () {
    if (this.value === 'none') {
        console.log('clicked none');
        if (!versionNum.classList.contains('hidden')) versionNum.classList.add('hidden');
        if (!jarName.classList.contains('hidden')) jarName.classList.add('hidden')
    } else {
        if (this.value) {
            console.log('clicked yes');
            if (versionNum.classList.contains('hidden')) versionNum.classList.remove('hidden');
            if (!jarName.classList.contains('hidden')) jarName.classList.add('hidden');
        } else{
            console.log('clicked no');
            if (!versionNum.classList.contains('hidden')) versionNum.classList.add('hidden');
            if (jarName.classList.contains('hidden')) jarName.classList.remove('hidden');
        }
    }
};
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="desc" for="get-latest-yn">Latest Binary?</label>
  <div>
    <select id="get-latest-yn" name="get-latest-yn" class="field select medium" tabindex="1">
      <option value="none"></option>
      <option value="true">Yes</option>
      <option value="false">No</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="version-num" class="hidden">
  clicked yes
</div>

<div id="jar-name" class="hidden">
  clicked no
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok stupid by me but the `value` datatype was `string` not `bool` so I changed

`this.value` to `this.value === 'true'`